# Minkowski-metric induct riamannian metric

Tags: analysis

> Let the Minkowski-metric on $\mathbb{R}^3$ be (for a p$\in \mathbb{R}^3, v,w\in T_p\mathbb{R}^3$) $<v,w>_p^{Mink}=-v_1w_1+v_2w_2+v_3w_3$.
>
> Show that:
>
> i) $H^2:=${$x\in\mathbb{R}^3|-x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=-1,x_1>0$} is a 2-dimensional under manifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and the Minkowski-metric induces a riemannian metric on $H^2$.
>
> ii) The stereographic projection with pole (-1,0,0), given as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \rightarrow \frac{1}{1+x_1}(x_2,x_3)^T$, is a isometry between $H^2$ and $B:=${$x\in\mathbb{R}^2|x_1^2+x_2^2<1$} with the metric $g_{ij}^x=\frac{4}{(1-x_1^2-x_2^2)^2}\delta_{ij}$

For i) I used the the regular value theorem to show that $H^2$ is an under manifold. But I don't know how the Minkowski-metric induces a riemannian metric. I already showed that it is symmetrical and a biliear form.
Could you give me a hint on how to show the positive definiteness, please?

For ii) I showed that the projection is surjektive and continuous. I don't know how to preceed here, because I don't know the inverse of the projection nor how to find it.

Thanks for any kind of help.